# SQL group in several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns (column1, column2 and column3) and data like this

```
column1      column2      column3
question1    question3    question5
question2    question4    question6
```

I like to count and group for each columns and result like this

```
column1   countc1    column2    countc2     column3     countc3
question1  10        question3    1         question5     12
question2  5         question4    2         question6     20
```

For example column1 has several questions which have multiple exact the same questions and I like group and count. 10 question1 and 5 question2

```
County     Zip       Direct
Lane       97230      west
Lane       97230      west
Medfore    97110      east
```

so the result (nc=new column count)

```
County  nc       ZIp   nc      Direct  nc 
Lane     2      97230  2       west    2
Medfore  1      97110  1       east    1
```

These columns will not relate to each other.

Comment: Where do the counts come from?  Did you make them up?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details there, not in comments where they can't be seen.

Comment: That looks like an awful design. Can you share your sample data and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Are the columns related in any way? County, Zip, Direct seems related, so you can use joins, but needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Select distinct column1, count_by_col1, column2, count_by_col2 
From (
Select column1,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS count_by_col1,
Column2,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column2) AS count_by_col2
From table1)
```

Comment: I have 3 columns and your example with 2 columns

Comment: Does above code gave correct result for 2 column? If yes, Add third, 4th, nth column according to logic above

Comment: Try this one 

`SELECT t1.col1, t1.count_by_col1 , t2.col2, t2.count_by_col2
FROM (
 SELECT row_number() over (order by [col1] asc) num,
  col1,
  count_by_col1
 FROM (
  Select distinct
  column1 col1,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS count_by_col1
  From MyTable) t1) t1

FULL JOIN (
SELECT row_number() over (order by [col2] asc) num,
 col2,
 count_by_col2
FROM (
 Select distinct
 column2 col2,
 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column2) AS count_by_col2
 From MyTable) t2 ) t2 ON (t1.num = t2.num) `

Comment: This worked. But I would reconsider what you want. What you want is not from design aspect

Comment: Here is another solution. results are same, but this solution uses group by instead of analytical functions

Comment: `SELECT t1.col1, t1.count_by_col1 , t2.col2, t2.count_by_col2
FROM (SELECT row_number() over (order by [col1] asc) num,
  col1,
  count_by_col1
FROM (
 Select COUNT(*) count_by_col1,
 column1 col1
 From MyTable
 GROUP BY column1 ) t1) t1

FULL JOIN (SELECT row_number() over (order by [col2] asc) num,
  col2,
  count_by_col2
FROM (
 Select COUNT(*) count_by_col2,
 column2 col2
 From MyTable
 GROUP BY column2 ) t2 ) t2 ON (t1.num = t2.num)`

Comment: I like to count and group for each columns if each columns have same records

Comment: Have you tried last 2 script examples that I have added to comments?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the values in separate *rows* rather than columns.  Is this close enough to what you want?

```
select which, val, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values ('county', county), ('zip', zip), ('direct', direct)
     ) v(which, val)
group by which, val
order by which, count(*) desc
```

Comment: 'v' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: @Tsang . . . As I say in the answer, the values are in ROWs not COLUMNs.  This may be sufficient for your purposes.